Arch Linux won't boot after changing grub option
I've posted a similar question, but only focusing on the final part which is where I am now, here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=299059

I wanted to add nomodeset to my grub options in an attempt to get my Arch Linux system to work with my Logitech Brio camera. I read a post suggesting that nomodeset might help, so I edited /etc/grub/default, and changed this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet"

to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet nomodeset"

And then ran grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg and rebooted. This seemed to have borked my grub. After rebooting, the machine went straight into the UEFI settings ("BIOS") and nothing I could change there seemed to make a difference, it kept rebooting over and over.
I booted into a live Linux system, mounted my local data and set up a chroot environment with (as root):
mkdir /mnt/foo
mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt/foo/
mount  /dev/nvme0n1p1  /mnt/foo/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do
   mount -B $i /mnt/foo/$i;
done

chroot /mnt/foo

/dev/nvme0n1p5 is my / partition, and /dev/nvme0n1p1 is my EFI partition. With this set up, from inside the chroot, I removed nomodeset from /etc/default/grub and then ran:
mkinitcpio -p linux
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi \
             --efi-directory=/efi \
             --bootloader-id=grub \
             --recheck

After rebooting, I could see my grub again, however, I cannot boot into the system. When I select Arch from the grub menu, I get the Loading Linux linux message (which is what grub echoes when this option is selected) but nothing happens. I am assuming it can't find my initramfs for some reason. This is the relevant grub menu entry:
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/nvme0n1p5 rw ibt=off loglevel=3 quiet
}

I repeated the steps above, and also tried running pacman -S linux from inside the chroot environment, and that also didn't fix it. The command worked, it reinstalled the linux package, but it made no difference.
One further complication is that my /home is on an encrypted partition, so I also need to be prompted to decrypt on boot. I suspect this will work normally if I can get the thing to boot though.
What else can I try here?

I discovered that one of the fallback entries in grub did let me boot. The relevant entry was:
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d rw ibt=off loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    }

That started booting but dropped me into a rescue shell. In the rescue shell, I set up my encrypted home with
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p6 home
mount /dev/mapper/home /home

Then exited the rescue shell with Ctrl + D and it booted normally! This now makes me think the issue might be more about the encrypted partition than anything else. Although that does seem odd given that the normal grub option only gets to echo 'Loading Linux linux ...' and nothing else.
Anyway, it seems like I can boot if I can fallback onto initrd since the only real difference between the working and non working grub entries is that the working one has
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d rw ibt=off loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img

while the non-working, default one, only has the linux line, no initrd. OK, so how can I fix the main one? Or is it not worth it and I should just use initrd?
This is my current /etc/mkinitcpio:
$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
MODULES=()
BINARIES=()
FILES=()
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect microcode modconf kms keyboard keymap consolefont block encrypt filesystems fsck )


Following the advice of Z00M, I added debug to the kernel options of the first grub entry, the one that doesn't load, and that got me to some more useful info:

The specific errors seem to be:
/dev/root: Can't open blockdev
VFS: Cannot open root device "/dev/nvme0n1p5" or unknown-block(0,0): error 6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option: here are the available partitions:
List of all bdev filesystems:
 fuseblk

Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

That is indeed my / partition, and when I boot using the fallback, I see:
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5  58066028 34254392  20829596  63% /

So why is grub not seeing it? I also tried changing the grub entry to use UUID and to have /boot/vmlinuz-linux instead of just /vmlinuz-linux which is what the non-working one has. So I made the non-working one be:

    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (edited by terdon)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=32133dd7-9a48-4b9d-b2e0-6e383e95631d rw ibt=off loglevel=3 quiet
    }

But that still won't boot. So it looks like I absolutely must have the initrd fallback option.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Might be relevant: "VFS: Cannot open root device "/dev/nvme0n1p5" or unknown-block(0,0): error 6" - the error code in the screenshot is -6.
